How to scrape a webpage url which is same as main page url in python?
The below website url opens a form , in which we only need to select fiscal year and click on search to get the data for that year, but the search year also opens the same url as below -
https://cfpub.epa.gov/compliance/criminal_prosecution/index.cfm

I have written below piece of code by manually putting the year xpath of 2023-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
b = webdriver.Chrome()
b.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
total_article_xpath = "//*[@id=\"main-content\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/div/div[2]/select/option[42]"
element = WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, total_article_xpath)))
time.sleep(10)
print(element)
getdetails = element.find_element(By.XPATH, total_article_xpath)
button_val = "//*[@id=\"searchButton\"]"
b.find_element(By.XPATH, button_val).click()
print(b)
vals = b.current_url

How can we navigate and scrape the fiscal year url which is same as main page url?
Any help would be appreciated.

Your code already seems to load a page, wait for it to load, find the button, and click it. If you were to wait for the page to update, what is stopping you from scraping it? Why do you think the URL is relevant to your problem? You're right that the URL is the same for the page without data present and the page with data loaded, but the "scraping" of a website is generally not related to the URL, but to whatever the values in the current document model are?

You need to make a selection from the Fiscal Year dropdown then click the Search button. You can then proceed to scrape the resulting page as normal.
Here's an example:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

URL = "https://cfpub.epa.gov/compliance/criminal_prosecution/index.cfm"
SELECT_XPATH = "//*[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/div/div[2]/select"
SEARCH_ID = "searchButton"
TBODY_XPATH = "//*[@id='main-content']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody"
FISCAL_YEAR = "2000"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    s = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, SELECT_XPATH))))
    if FISCAL_YEAR in {option.text for option in s.options}:
        s.select_by_visible_text(FISCAL_YEAR)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, SEARCH_ID))).click()
        tbody = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, TBODY_XPATH)))
        for td in tbody.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.valign-top")[::2]:
            print(td.text)
    else:
        print(f"{FISCAL_YEAR} is not an available option")

Output:
Allen Sinclair
BP Exploration-Alaska (BPXA)
Ben Shafsky
Doyon Drilling, Inc.
Michael Krupa


Hey, thank you very much. How can I get the View links from all the boxes and also from respective pages for that fiscal year, like for 2000 year , there are 3 pages , how can I get all View links ?

@emileymille For fiscal year 2000 there are 3 pages available. On the first page you will see hyperlinks to pages 2 & 3. Navigate to those and click them or execute the relevant Javascript
